# Is reversing the z-axis label in GAMs interaction plot statistically appropriate?

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, biostatistics, generalized-additive-model, mgcv

I have plotted a 3D perspective plot for generalized additive models. However, the z-axis label `Growers (proportion)` read from top to bottom. I have been asked to reverse the z-axis label, so `Growers (proportion)` reads from bottom to top. The `vis.gam()` function doesn't seem to have the function to rotate the z-axis title. However, my question is it legit to rotate the z-axis title? The direction of title or arrow indicate how high or low the value is. For example, when x1 is at the end of the arrow, this is it's maximum value. The opposite end is it's minimum value. There are many examples where the axes title is from top to bottom, so I am not certain it's a legit advice. Any referred explanation would be appreciated.   https://esajournals.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/full/10.1890/ES11-00128.1

https://scholar.google.com/citations?user=EskiIyEAAAAJ&hl=en

https://scholar.google.com/citations?user=EskiIyEAAAAJ&hl=en

My code & plot

```
n <- 200
sig2 <- 4
x1 <- runif(n, 0, 1)
x2 <- runif(n, 0, 1)
x3 <- runif(n, 0, 1)
x4 <- runif(n, 0, 1)
y <- x1^2 + x1 * x2 * x4

mod <- gam(y ~ s(x1, x2) + s(x3, x4))


p1 <- wrap_elements(panel = ~vis.gam(mod, view = c("x1",  "x2"), zlab = "Growers (proportion)", 
                                     theta = 120, plot.type = "persp", type = "response", ticktype = "detailed"))
p2 <- wrap_elements(panel = ~vis.gam(mod, view = c("x3",  "x4"), zlab = "Growers (proportion)", 
                                     theta = 35, plot.type = "persp", type = "response", ticktype = "detailed"))

fig <- p1 + p2 + plot_layout(ncol = 2, tag_level = 'new') +
  plot_annotation(tag_levels = list(c('(a)', '(b)'))) 
fig
```

As you can see, the Z-axis Growers (proportion) reads from top to bottom
[image]

Comment: It is entirely valid, though I don't think it is possible with `persp()` plots, so you might need to do this outside of R in a vector graphics application, like Inkscape or Adobe Illustrator. A bigger problem is panel a) which implies the model predicts outside the bounds for a proportion (>1.0)

Comment: @GavinSimpson Thanks. That's just simulated data - predictions are within the range for original data. I guess I have to reduce the distance between plot annotations `(a)` and `(b)` and plots in Inkscape too?

Comment: So the `gam()` code is just pseudocode and not the full model (it's missing an appropriate `family`)? You can fix to some extent the space; you need to look at graphical parameters in ?par and reduce the margins to be as small as possible. Having done that, the a) and b) should be close to the perspective plots *if* you draw on a device that is ~ twice as wide as it is tall, so, set the the `height` and `width` when `ggsave()`-ing.

Comment: Thanks very much! Yes, the code is pseudo code just to produce plots.